# Not able to combine multiple rows into single row based on certain conditions

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, pivot

[image: Table strucuture]

In the image above, i have shown table structure i use to store result of student. However I need to select data in such a manner such that depending on particular FEID(examination ID),
I get marks obtained and subID of single student in single row. Something like below:

```
 FEID  SubID1  MarksObtained  SubID2  MarksObtained  SubID3  MarksObtained  StdID  
 2     1       0              2       0              3       0              50         
 2     1       45             2       45             3       45             51
```

Result Column wont affect outcome as for a particular stdID and FEID it remains same for no matter how many SubID are there. 
Basically I am storing each subject marks in single row and subjects are can be any number( more than 3 as in this case) , which is not known before hand. But for each I create one row to enter its marks

I tried sytax below .

```
  DECLARE @cols nvarchar(MAX);
    --get the list of subids from the table
    SELECT @cols =  SubjectName from tbSubjects where SubID IN(select distinct SubID from tbFinalMarks);

    Declare @sql nvarchar(MAX) = 'SELECT StdId, FEID, ' + @cols + 'FROM 
    (
    SELECT * FROM tbFinalMarks
    )t
    PIVOT
    (
      MAX(MarksObtained) FOR SubId IN (' + @cols + ')

)p';
```

Comment: You need to use a pivot table to do this.

Comment: I have never used pivot table. Is there any reference for the same which i may look up

Comment: I will add an answer that shows an example

Comment: waiting for ur answer @pquest

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this will do it. It will also dynamically add new columns for new sub ids without you needing to worry about it.

```
    DECLARE @cols nvarchar(MAX);
    --get the list of subids from the table
    SELECT @cols = COALESCE(@cols + ',', '') + '[' + CAST(SubId AS nvarchar) + ']' FROM (SELECT DISTINCT SubId FROM table);

    Declare @sql nvarchar(MAX) = 'SELECT StdId, FEID, ' + @cols + 'FROM 
    (
    SELECT * FROM table
    )t
    PIVOT
    (
      MAX(MarksObtained) FOR SubId IN (' + @cols + ')

)p';

EXECUTE sp_executesql @sql;
```

Comment: its throwing an error , colum1 was specified multiple times

Comment: it is not working, and i modified it a bit, i now am getting subject names on the basis of their id as...

Comment: You need that COALESCE in there. That is what turns it into a comma separated list of subjects you also need to modify the SELECT * FROM table portion to include the subject name join if you want to see them like that.

Answer (score 0):

Although you can use `pivot`, I think the explicit aggregation approach is easier to construct:

```
select feid,
       1 as SubId_1,
       max(case when SubId = 1 then MarksObtained end) as MarksObtained_1,
       2 as SubId_2,
       max(case when SubId = 2 then MarksObtained end) as MarksObtained_2,
       3 as SubId_3,
       max(case when SubId = 3 then MarksObtained end) as MarksObtained_3,
       stdid
from table t
group by feid, stdid;
```

Comment: The number of rows to be binded together is not known beforehand, in above case it was three as that exam had only 3 subjects. If exam has for example 5 subjects, 5 rows will be created. So i think there needs to be loop somwhere in query. !!  @Gordon Linoff